# Creating new columns based on value of other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

In my `df` I have a column for each entity below (Grubhub, Toasttab, Tenk) and it says either yes or no in the value of that column for each row,

I have below code such as:

```
df['Grubhub'] = df[['On GrubHub or Seamless?']].apply(lambda x: any(x == 'Yes'), axis = 1)

df['ToastTab'] = df[['On ToastTab?']].apply(lambda x: any(x == 'Yes'), axis = 1)

df['Tenk'] = df[['On Tenk?']].apply(lambda x: any(x == 'Yes'), axis = 1)

df['Udemy'] = df[['On Udmey?']].apply(lambda x: any(x == 'Yes'), axis = 1)

df['Postmates'] = df[['On Postmates?']].apply(lambda x: any(x == 'Yes'), axis = 1)

df['Doordash'] = df[['On DoorDash?']].apply(lambda x: any(x == 'Yes'), axis = 1)

df['Google'] = df[['On Goole?']].apply(lambda x: any(x == 'Yes'), axis = 1)
```

This gives me a new column for each entity ( Grubhub, Toasttab, Tenk ) and that column gives a true of false value, is there a more efficient method where I can do all of these in one line of code or function? Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a column map and apply a `function` inside `loop`:

```
columns_map = (
    ('Grubhub', 'On GrubHub or Seamless?'),
    ('ToastTab', 'On ToastTab?'),
    ('Tenk', 'On Tenk?'),
    # etc ...
)

for new_col, alias in columns_map:
    df[new_col] = df[alias].apply(lambda x: x == 'Yes')
    # also you can easily remove aliases columns:
    # df = df.drop(columns=[alias])
```

Or you can set value into original column and rename if you need(without `drop()`):

```
for new_col, alias in columns_map:
    df[alias] = df[alias].apply(lambda x: x == 'Yes')

df.rename(
    columns={alias: new_col for new_col, alias in columns_map},
    inplace=True
)
```